# How to open port in Win7 Firewall using Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, port, delphi-xe2, firewall

i want to open a port in Windows 7 Firewall for port forwarding via Delphi but as been said in other threads windows 7 has Multiple Profiles in Firewall (Public, Private) and the next code only adds the exception to one of them.

Code:

```
procedure addPortToFirewall(EntryName:string;PortNumber:Cardinal); 
Const 
  NET_FW_PROFILE_DOMAIN = 0; 
  NET_FW_PROFILE_STANDARD = 1; 
  NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY = 2; 
  NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP = 17; 
  NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6; 
  NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL = 0; 
  NET_FW_SCOPE_LOCAL_SUBNET = 1;var 
  fwMgr,port:OleVariant; 
  profile:OleVariant; 
begin 
  fwMgr := CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FwMgr'); 
  profile := fwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile; 
  port := CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FWOpenPort'); 
  port.Name := EntryName; 
  port.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP; 
  port.Port := PortNumber; 
  port.Scope := NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL; 
  port.Enabled := true; 
  profile.GloballyOpenPorts.Add(port); 
end;
```

I know that this is the code used for Windows XP but the one for Win 7 i cannot locate how to open a port and not an application.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
const
NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN  = 1;
NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2;
NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC  = 4;
NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW    = 1;
var
  fwPolicy2      : OleVariant;
  RulesObject    : OleVariant;
  Profile        : Integer;
  NewRule        : OleVariant;
begin
  Profile             := NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE OR NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
  fwPolicy2           := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RulesObject         := fwPolicy2.Rules;
  NewRule             := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule');
  NewRule.Name        := 'Test Firwwall';
  NewRule.Description := 'Test Firewall';
  NewRule.Applicationname := 'Exe File';
  NewRule.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
  NewRule.Enabled := TRUE;
  NewRule.Profiles := Profile;
  NewRule.Action := NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
  RulesObject.Add(NewRule);
end;
```

For the final just to make all of this clear, how do i open A port in windows 7 Firewall using delphi? for multiple profiles (Private, Public).

Thank you in regards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To open a port under Windows 7 you must specify  the `LocalPorts` and `Direction` properties of the `HNetCfg.FWRule` object. This is explainded in the MSDN Documentation [`Using Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

procedure AddExceptionToFirewall(Const Caption, Executable: String;Port : Word);
const
NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN  = 1;
NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2;
NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC  = 4;

NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW    = 1;
NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN  = 1;
NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT = 2;
var
  fwPolicy2      : OleVariant;
  RulesObject    : OleVariant;
  Profile        : Integer;
  NewRule        : OleVariant;
begin
  Profile             := NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE OR NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
  fwPolicy2           := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RulesObject         := fwPolicy2.Rules;
  NewRule             := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule');
  NewRule.Name        := Caption;
  NewRule.Description := Caption;
  NewRule.Applicationname := Executable;
  NewRule.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
  NewRule.LocalPorts :=  Port;
  NewRule.Direction := NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT;
  NewRule.Enabled := TRUE;
  NewRule.Grouping := 'My Group';
  NewRule.Profiles := Profile;
  NewRule.Action := NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
  RulesObject.Add(NewRule);
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      AddExceptionToFirewall('MyAppRule','MyApp.exe', 3307);
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Note : This code requires elevation.

Comment: Thanks!!! worked like a charm, its just im not used to use OleObjects and sometimes get lost in the MSDN documentation, althrough i tried to find it in there the LocalPort Property but could not find it. Anyways thanks for the code!!!

Comment: May I ask for one more info? I added another ole object to set inbound as well as outbound, but I can't seem to find info on how to set port on rule to "Any". Is there a possibility to do so, or does the port need to be specified?

Comment: Nevermind. It goes to "Any" if I don't specify the port at all... :)