# How to Open Port in Windows Firewall using C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

I get an error when I compile my project in Borland C++Builder:

> 'Add' is not a member of 'Variant'

I tried to do this using the Automation API, but it gives me the error above:

```cpp
const NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN  = 1;
const NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2;
const NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC  = 4;

const NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
const NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP = 17;
const NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW    = 1;
const NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN  = 1;
const NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT = 2;

Variant fwPolicy2, RulesObject, NewRule;
DWORD Profile;

Profile   = NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE | NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
fwPolicy2 = CreateOleObject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
RulesObject = fwPolicy2.OlePropertyGet("Rules");
NewRule   = CreateOleObject("HNetCfg.FWRule");
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Name") = "Text Firewall";
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Description") = "Text Firewall";
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Applicationname") = "System_RCC.exe";
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Protocol")   = NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("LocalPorts") = Edit1->Text;
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Direction")  = NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT;
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Enabled")   = true;
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Grouping")  = "";
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Profiles")  = Profile;
NewRule.OlePropertyGet("Action")  = NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
RulesObject.Add(NewRule);
```

Note: this code is taken from here:

[How to open port in Win7 Firewall using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066467/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RulesObject` is a [`System::Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variant) wrapping a COM object.

In Delphi, `(Ole)Variant` handles access to a COM object's properties and methods transparently for you (the compiler translates the calls into invocations of the `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()` and `IDispatch::Invoke()` interface methods). That is why the Delphi code you link to is very straight forward.

In C++, however, you have to use the [`Variant::OleProcedure()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variant.OleProcedure) or [`Variant::OleFunction()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variant.OleFunction) method to invoke a COM object's methods, just like you have to use the `Variant::OleProperty(Get|Set)()` methods to access a COM object's properties.  The `Variant::Ole...()` methods perform similar `IDispatch` invocations that Delphi performs.

In addition, when populating `NewRule`, you need to use `OlePropertySet()` instead of `OlePropertyGet()`.

Try this:

```cpp
const NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN = 1;
const NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2;
const NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC = 4;

const NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
const NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP = 17;
const NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW = 1;
const NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN = 1;
const NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT = 2;

Variant fwPolicy2, RulesObject, NewRule;
DWORD Profile;

Profile = NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE | NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
fwPolicy2 = CreateOleObject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"); RulesObject = fwPolicy2.OlePropertyGet("Rules");
NewRule = CreateOleObject("HNetCfg.FWRule");
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Name", WideString("Text Firewall"));
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Description", WideString("Text Firewall"));
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Applicationname", WideString("System_RCC.exe"));
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Protocol", NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP);
NewRule.OlePropertySet("LocalPorts", Edit1->Text);
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Direction", NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT);
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Enabled", true);
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Grouping", WideString(""));
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Profiles", Profile);
NewRule.OlePropertySet("Action", NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW);
RulesObject.OleProcedure("Add", NewRule);
```

Comment: Now i get an exception at `RulesObject.OleProcedure("Add", NewRule);` saying **Parameter is incorrect**, `First chance exception at $7579AA12. Exception class EOleException with message 'The parameter is incorrect'. Process Project1.exe (10100)`

Comment: Thank you, that however solved it, but you forgot to add `NewRule.OlePropertySet("LocalPorts", WideString(Edit1->Text));`, also **Administrator privileges is required**

Comment: @Jack `Edit1->Text` returns a `System::String`, which does not need to be explicit casts to `WideString` when calling `Variant::Ole...()` methods, `Variant` will handle the `String` data correctly. The same is not true for `char*` strings such as string literals, they are not interrupted correctly as strings, hence the explicit casts to `WideString`. And yes, of course admin privileges are required to modify firewall settings